# loggedfs crashes system with "access: Transport endpoint is not connected"

Tags: linux, monitoring, fuse

I'm trying to use loggedfs to monitor my system changes, and it works great for some time, but then, eventually, it crashes and my fish shell starting to output "access: Transport endpoint is not connected" everytime I try to enter some command. To fix this, I have to login from other terminal as a root and run `fusermount -zu <homeforlder>` command to resolve that.
Where should I look to find what causes such behavior of the system? Can someone point me where to look? Thx.

Command I run: `loggedfs -f -p /home -c /home/sandric/loggedfs.xml`

P.S. I actually working on web-frontend to loggedfs [here](https://github.com/sandric/loggedfs-web) and it crashes there, so if anyone can point it as an issue there, I will be appreciated too.